# How to add a new row to another sheet without overwriting the row in VBA?

Tags: vba

I have 2 sheets. I want to transfer a fixed range (a row of data) from sheet #1 (data sheet) to sheet #2 (info sheet) by clicking on a command button. The transferred data should be kept as records in sheet #2. But when I use the code below it overwrites the existing entry instead of adding a new record (row). How do I add a new row to sheet #2 and not overwrite the existing one?

```vb
Sheets("DATA").Select

Range("B85:G85").Select

Selection.copy

Sheets("INFO").Select

Range("B5").Select

ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select

Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

Sheets("DATA").Select

Range("B86:G86").Select

Application.CutCopyMode = False

Selection.copy

Sheets("INFO ").Select

Range("H5").Select

ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select

Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

Comment: No need to [shout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_caps#Association_with_shouting)

Comment: You might benefit from this. [Avoid Using Select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem with the Code:**

- No calculation of Last Row
- Excessive use of Select

**Try this:**

```
With Sheets("INFO")

Sheets("DATA").Range("B85:G85").Copy
.Range("B" & .Range("B5").End(xlDown).row + 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

Sheets("DATA").Range("B86:G86").Copy
.Range("H" & .Range("H5").End(xlDown).row + 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

End With
```

Comment: It worked, thank you so much. Appreciate your quick response and help.

Comment: Cool, Accept the Answer :)